# PHP with AWASP framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

Who here is using WASP (http://wasp.sourceforge.net/content/) to in real world applications? What impressions do you have? Good? Bad? If you can provide any inputs, how good it is comparing with rails for example.

I'm really looking for MVC frameworks for PHP

> **Update:** [This comparation](http://www.phpit.net/article/ten-different-php-frameworks/) I found is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded it a while ago and tried it out, but as the documentation is pretty terrible at the moment (consisting of some auto-generated 'documentation' that was useless) I gave up pretty quickly. I think one of the most important things to have in a framework is clear, thorough documentation - if you have to spend time digging through the code of the framework to find out if a class you want exists, the point of using a framework is lost. WASP does not seem to be ready for production environments just yet, as even their website admits that its not ready for enterprise applications.

If you're looking for a PHP framework I would recommend CodeIgniter, which has excellent documentation and a helpful community, or Zend, which is pretty mature.

Answer (score 2):

[CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org) is a great framework with great documentation. Symfony lost me with all the configuration, at the time I was new to both frameworks and CakePHP stood out as being the best for me and I was able to pick it up very quickly

Answer (score 1):

Hey Victor, that comparison is pretty badly out of date. It was done about 1.5 years ago and, at least in the case of the Zend Framework that I use regularly,things have changed greatly since then. I'd say that comparison is so old as to be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Check out symfony, too. Free software, top-notch documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[QCodo](http://www.qcodo.com) is great - amazing code generation, full MVC support. The strongest object-relational mapping I've seen; their scaffolding model is so much stronger than CakePHP and Zend... Plus, it's beautifully extensible with community controls. I've been using it for large projects for the last two years, it's great!

Comment: I was excited about QCodo in the past, and dabbled with it. I'm not so sure about its future though. The original project architect is not actively working on it anymore and it seems to be undergoing a semi-fork. Kind of interesting. Anyone can read up on it at the qcodo forum.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)?
I tested CakePHP but it's too much a la Rails style and i didn't like it.
CodeIgniter gives you more freedom to do whatever you whant.